# achieving excel filter with multiple criteria in single column

Tags: excel, filter, criteria

I have an excel worksheet, where i maintain list of application names may be 1000 rows, i would like to filter the rows based on say list of applications like "App1 OR App12 OR App22". Filter option allows only two such OR condition that can be added.

How to add multiple OR conditions up to 20 to 30 values. Is there a short cut or vba available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your data structure in sheet, it is hard to advise correct method. I would suggest to build a criteria list that you want to filter. Then use `FILTER()` function with `COUNTIFS()`. Try the following formula.

```
=FILTER(A2:A11,COUNTIFS(H2:H4,B2:B11))
```

[image]